# Power a Micrcontroller Using a 12 Volt Battery

Tags: battery-charging

I have a solar panel that is charging a 12 volt battery through a charge controller. The battery is used to apply voltage to a pump. I would like to use the battery to power the micro-controller. What is the best way to do this? The micro-controller needs 3.3 V.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the current needs of your microcontroller, a linear or switching voltage regulator.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about a switching regulator for this. If all you need to do is turn on a MOSFET to switch on the pump then you won't need more than 15mA if even that much and a linear regulator will be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Many solutions for converting 12v DC to 3.3v DC

1. Using simple linear regulator IC, for example [LD1117V33](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/526) ~ 800mA or [NTE1904](http://www.digipart.com/part/NTE1904) ~ 1A. You only need 3 components: 10uF capacitor (at input and output) and the IC itself.
2. Using old but very popular LM317 ~ 1A or LM350 ~ 3A. You need minimum 5 components. See schematic [here](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-N8fWdFhlouc/TnRG85acliI/AAAAAAAAA5k/dPA56ZxMfQ0/s1600/3.3V+regulated.jpg).
3. Using switching regulator IC, such as LM2576-3.3, ISL8510,  etc. You may consider to build it by yourself or purchase from the manufacturer/distributor, example: [adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1066), [pololu](https://www.pololu.com/category/131/step-down-voltage-regulators), etc

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother with linear regulators anymore. Their time is over in my opinion. Especially if you want to use a battery where **efficiency is important.**

I would only use linear regulators in projects where efficiency isn't important- which more and more die out because - **let's think green!**

I would highly recommend a step-down voltage generator like the LM2596. Efficiency is a category where step downs/ups really shine because they don't generate so much heat in the conversion process which isn't usable - at least not for our purpose.

The LM2596 is more than overkill in terms of input range and output current but because it is so commonly used in many devices, the price is still pretty low.

If you don't have your multimeter at hand you might consider this here.

**[DROK® LM2596 NC Buck Converter DC-DC Step-down Transformer Voltage Regulator Module 36V 24V 12V to 5V 2A Power Inverter Volt Stabilizer with Red LED Display Voltmeter Board Input/Output Voltage](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JUFJ1GA)**

If you have a **trustworthy** multimeter I would recommend this pack which contains 2 of them. You might find a purpose for it in another project soon.

**[Retailstore 2PCS LM2596 Buck DC-DC Adjustable Step Down Power Supply Module Converter New](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009HPB1OI)**

Comment: Efficiency matters, but sometimes a switcher's efficiency at low currents is lower than a linear regs.